# Accessing kivy screen ids in on_start method

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to add widgets to a screen in the `on_start` method but I was getting a Key Error for the screen id I was trying to access. So, I printed out `self.root.ids` and it's an empty dictionary.

Is this something to do with the screens having not been populated in the `on_start` method?

main.py

```
class SelectChat(Screen):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        kv = Builder.load_file("kivy.kv")
        self.sm = WindowManager()

        screens = [SelectChat(name="select_chat")]
        for screen in screens:
            self.sm.add_widget(screen)

        self.sm.current = "select_chat"
        return self.sm


    def on_start(self):
        self.docs = self.my_firestore.db.collection(u'users').where(u'value', u'==', True).stream()
        print(self.root.ids) #This is producing the empty dict
        #select_chat = self.root.ids['select_chat'].ids['select_chat_grid'] # This is where I get the key error
```

main.kv

```
<SelectChat>:
    name: "select_chat"
    id: select_chat

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        id: select_chat_grid
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the reason but I found the answer.

I had to change

```
select_chat = self.root.ids['select_chat'].ids['select_chat_grid']
```

to:

```
select_chat = self.root.get_screen("select_chat").ids['select_chat_grid']
```

So I had to reference the screen name, not the screen id